# How to restore an environmental variable on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Ok, I did a really, really stupid thing the other night while trying to install JDK 1.6 (older version, I know, but it's for an online class I'm taking and for some reason that's the version the teacher is using).

I went to environmental variables to create a path for my Java and inadvertently deleted the original environmental path, so, of course, I cannot even launch JDK.

How can I reinstall the original path on Windows 10?  I tried regedit but am a little clueless where to go from here.

**EDIT:**

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but now I get this error on reinstall

> Error 1723, There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run.

Comment: "original environmental path" for what? You need to add more details in your question, it is unclear in its present form. Try uninstalling and reinstalling JDK?

Comment: Hi-  Yes, I tried unistalling jdk and then reinstalling.  I'm getting a DLL errror.

Comment: Says Error 1723, There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run....

Comment: I found this...https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Environmental Variable again.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-U9SGaNbwY

Hit the start button on your computer

go to environmental variables

select *new*

Name -

> JAVA_HOME

Value -

> jdk-install-dir

Or at least that's what i got from google.

Your machine might need a reboot for it to stick.